# Derivative of series of non-decreasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of non-decreasing functions on $[0,1]$ such that
$$F(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1} f_n(x)$$
converges for all $x\in[0,1]$. I would like to show that
$$F'(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1} f_n'(x)$$
almost everywhere. I compute
$$\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}{h}$$
so that
$$F'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{f_n(x+h)-f_n(x)}{h}.$$
I know that each $f_n(x)$ is almost-everywhere differentiable by virtue of its monotonicity but am not sure how to justify exchanging limit and sum.

Comment: You may want to use Dini's second or first theorem (don't remember which one) on $f_n$ or $\sum_{k<n}f_k'$ this will give you some nice uniform convergence

Comment: You can exchange them since they are positive

Comment: Do you mean non-negative? If so, what theorem justifies this?

Comment: Do you know of any theorems that allow you to swap a sum of functions and a limit? If so, how could your one hypothesis on $f$ help you apply them?

Comment: Yes positive in French means non-negative

Answer (score -2):

We can find measurable functions $g_n:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^+$ such that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
$$f_n(x)=\int_0^xg_n(t)dt,$$
where this is a Lebesgue integral. It is not hard to see that we can add up all $g$'s, since their integral measures add up to a finite number. So, let's define:
$$g:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^+:x\mapsto\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(x).$$
This function is defined almost everywhere, and that's as much as we need. Now we can see that:
$$\int_0^xg(t)dt=\int_0^x\sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(t)dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\int_0^x g_n(t)dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)=F(x)$$
holds almost everywhere. In other words, we found a Radon-Nykodim derivative of $F$ and it is equal to your guess a.e.

Comment: Let $q_k$ denote the sequence of all rational numbers in $[0,1].$ Let $f_1(x)=\sum_{k,\,q_k\le x}{1\over 2^k}.$ The function $f_1$ is increasing, but $f_1$ is not absolutely continuous.

Comment: Why can we find the $g_n$? Wouldn’t that representation for $f_n$ in terms of $g_n$ imply that $f_n$ is absolutely continuous?

Comment: okkkkkkk, handle the singular functions separately. the countable sum of singular functions is a singular function

Comment: The countable sum of singular functions is not necessarily a singular function. The result may or may not be singular depending on the behavior of the individual functions and specific terms being summed. Some combinations of singular functions may cancel out their singularities, leading to a non-singular function; others may lead to an accumulation of singularities, resulting in yet another singular function.

Comment: @RyRytheFlyGuy You just can't stop yourself lol.